# Generate random BMP in CLI

Tags: image, random, command-line-interface

I need a truly random BMP in order to test various lossy image compression algorithms. Ideally, this would not rely on any library and run in a Linux CLI.

It should generate a random BMP given a certain `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Updated Answer - April 2021**

Here are some more ideas for random images:

---

Random coloured squares

```
magick -size 8x8 xc: +noise Random -scale 100x100 RandomColouredSquares.png
```

[image]

---

Random black and white crosswords

```
magick -size 8x8 xc:gray +noise Random -threshold 50% -scale 100x100 RandomCrosswords.png
```

[image]

---

Random grey blur

```
magick -size 8x8 xc:gray +noise Random -resize 100x100 RandomGreyBlur.png
```

[image]

---

Random coloured blur

```
magick -size 5x5 xc: +noise Random -auto-level -resize 100x100 RandomColouredBlur.png
```

[image]

---

Random salt and pepper

```
magick -size 100x100 xc:gray +noise Random -threshold 1% -negate RandomSaltAndPepper.png
```

[image]

---

Repeated coloured pattern

```
magick -size 50x50 xc: +noise random -virtual-pixel tile -blur 0x6 -auto-level -write MPR:tile +delete -size 250x250 tile:MPR:tile RandomRepeatedPattern.png
```

[image]

**Updated Answer - March 2021**

If you want random-noise type of images, see original answer below, noting that you should replace `convert` with `magick` in those examples if working with **ImageMagick** v7 onwards.

If you want images of a solid random colour, you could do something like this:

```
magick -size 400x200 xc:"rgb($((RANDOM%255)),$((RANDOM%255)),$((RANDOM%255)))" image.png
```

*Sample Outputs*

[image]

[image]

---

If you want images of a random size and a random solid colour, you could use this for images between 200..264 pixels wide by 100..132 pixels tall:

```
magick -size "$(((RANDOM%64)+200))x$(((RANDOM%32)+100))" xc:"rgb($((RANDOM%255)),$((RANDOM%255)),$((RANDOM%255)))"random.png
```

*Sample Outputs*

[image]

[image]

**Original Answer**

You can use `ImageMagick` (which is installed on most Linux distros by default) to generate an image of random noise like this:

```
convert -size 300x200 xc:gray +noise random out.bmp
```

where `300` is the width and `200` is the height (just examples).

Other types of noise are available, just run

```
convert -list noise
```

**Output**

```
Gaussian
Impulse
Laplacian
Multiplicative
Poisson
Random
Uniform
```

If the noise is too noisy ;-) for you, you can attenuate it with

```
convert -size 300x200 xc:gray -attenuate 0.5 +noise random out.bmp
```

for a 50% attenuation

Here are some examples of the different types:

[image]

Here are the corresponding distribution histograms:

[image]

---

Just for completeness, note that this answer features in Daniel Barrett's book *"Efficient Linux at the Command Line"*.

Comment: Use `xc:wheat` or other such options like `khaki, transparent, none` etc if you want color or transparent images.

Comment: convert 1.bmp -colorspace Gray -define histogram:unique-colors=false histogram:1h.bmp