# How to replace all pixels of a certain RGB value with another RGB value in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, colors, pixel

I need to be able to replace all pixels that have a certain RGB value with another color in OpenCV.

I’ve tried some of the solutions but none of them worked for me.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Try updating the question with what you've tried.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: I know, it was working about 15 minutes ago. I think it’s down temporarily

Comment: LUT is an efficient way if you have multiple of those replaced colors

Answer (score 27, accepted):

TLDR; Make all green pixels white with Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

pixels[np.all(pixels == (0, 255, 0), axis=-1)] = (255,255,255)
```

---

I have made some examples of other ways of changing colours here. First I'll cover exact, specific RGB values like you asked in your question, using this image. It has three big blocks of exactly red, exactly green and exactly blue on the left and three gradual transitions between those colours on the right:

[image]

Here's the initial answer as above again:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('image.png')

# Make all perfectly green pixels white
im[np.all(im == (0, 255, 0), axis=-1)] = (255,255,255)

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result1.png',im)
```

[image]

---

This time I define the colour names for extra readability and maintainability. The final line is the important point:

```
# Define some colours for readability - these are in OpenCV **BGR** order - reverse them for PIL
red   = [0,0,255]
green = [0,255,0]
blue  = [255,0,0]
white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]

# Make all perfectly green pixels white
im[np.all(im == green, axis=-1)] = white
```

Same result.

---

This time I make a re-usable mask of red pixels which I can use in subsequent operations. The final line with the assignment `im[Rmask] = black` is now particularly easy to read :

```
# Define some colours for readability - these are in OpenCV **BGR** order - reverse them for PIL
red   = [0,0,255]
green = [0,255,0]
blue  = [255,0,0]
white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]

# Make mask of all perfectly red pixels
Rmask = np.all(im == red, axis=-1)

# Make all red pixels black
im[Rmask] = black
```

[image]

---

This time I **combine** a mask of red and blue pixels so you can see the power of masks. The final line is the important point:

```
# Define some colours for readability - these are in OpenCV **BGR** order - reverse them for PIL
red   = [0,0,255]
green = [0,255,0]
blue  = [255,0,0]
white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]

# Make mask of all perfectly red pixels and all perfectly blue pixels
Rmask = np.all(im == red,  axis=-1)
Bmask = np.all(im == blue, axis=-1)

# Make all red or blue pixels black
im[Rmask | Bmask] = black
```

[image]

---

And this time I make all non-red pixels into black - hopefully you are appreciating the power of masks now. The final line is the important point:

```
# Define some colours for readability - these are in OpenCV **BGR** order - reverse them for PIL
red   = [0,0,255]
green = [0,255,0]
blue  = [255,0,0]
white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]

# Make mask of all perfectly red pixels
Rmask = np.all(im == red,  axis=-1)

# Make all non-red pixels black
im[~Rmask] = black
```

[image]

---

Up till now, we have only made some selection of pixels into a single new colour. What if we want to make some pixels one colour and all other pixels a different colour in a single pass? The final line is the important point:

```
# Define some colours for readability - these are in OpenCV **BGR** order - reverse them for PIL
red   = [0,0,255]
green = [0,255,0]
blue  = [255,0,0]
white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]

# Make mask of all perfectly red pixels
Rmask = np.all(im == red,  axis=-1)

# Make all red pixels white AND at same time everything else black
im = np.where(np.all(im == red, axis=-1, keepdims=True), white, black)
```

[image]

---

If you want to affect a whole **range** of colours, rather than a specific RGB value, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215020/2836621) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52183666/2836621).

**Keywords**: Image processing, Python, prime, change colour, change color, prime.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can do this with a range of colors? So instead of green, I replace all colors close to green?

Comment: Yes, of course. Have a look here. It starts off with PIL but that makes no difference really - the technique is just the same. I'll make this answer more comprehensive in the next day or two. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52183666/2836621

Comment: Thank you! This wasn’t what I was planning to do but masks seem like a good way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the 'certain' pixels which you need to change have the following RGB values:
[r,g,b] i.e. the pixels have R=r, G=g and B=b as color values.

Firstly you need to create a 2D mask of the same size as your image. Let the size be (X,Y). The mask should:

1. Have value 1 or True at index (x1,y1) if the corresponding pixels in image has RGB channels==[r,g,b]
2. Have value 0 or False at index (x2,y2) if the corresponding pixels in image has RGB channels!=[r,g,b]

To create this mask:

```
old_color = [r,g,b]
new_color = [r2,g2,b2]

height, width, channels = numpy.shape(image)
mask = numpy.zeros((height,width))
# iterate over all pixels in the image and assign 0 to the mask(x,y) if image(x,y) has channels==old_color
mask= [[1 if np.all(channels==[old_color]) else 0 for channels in row ] for row in image ]
```

Then find the coordinates of all the 1s in the mask, these are the coordinate where you need to assign the new color in the image. Simply use np.where() to find the coordinates.

```
mask = numpy.array(mask) # make sure that mask is a numpy array not a list of lists
# numpy.where would not work otherwise
coords_x, coord_y = np.where(mask>0)
```

Finally change the RGB values on these coordinates in the image with the new RGB value:

```
img_cp = image.copy()
img_cp[coords_x,coord_y,:]=new_color
```

Your selected pixels in the image have new colors now. You can check with `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(img_cp)`