# My code is detecting colors other than what I am looking for

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, game-automation

I am trying to make a Python bot for a Roblox game where you hit spacebar whenever a white bar hovers over a yellow bar. However I am having a problem detecting the right color pixels. Whenever I try to check for pixels with a RGB value of 255,255,0 it gets colors other then yellow like light green and white.

```py
import random
import cv2
import keyboard
import numpy as np

game_img = cv2.imread('test.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
dodge_img = cv2.imread('dodge8.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

print(type(game_img))
print(game_img.shape)

for y in range(0,game_img.shape[0]):
    for x in range(0,game_img.shape[1]):
        if np.any(game_img[y][x] == [255,255,0]):
            game_img[y][x] = [random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255)]

cv2.imshow("this", game_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

Image After "yellow" pixels were changed:

[image: Image After "yellow" pixels were changed]

Comment: OpenCV uses colors (and channels) as BGR not RGB, so yellow would be (0,255,255)

Comment: Changing the pixel check to be 0,255,255 also doesnt appear to quite work correctly, it then detects every red, yellow, white, and green color.

Comment: You've missed the point of Numpy operations if you are looping with `for` loops. The idea is to process the entire image with a single call. There are many easily-followed examples here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019059/2836621

Comment: why are you using `np.any`? when will that be true?

Comment: Just use cv2.inRange() to make a mask for whatever color you want. Then use the mask to change that color or do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

`np.any(game_img[y][x] == [255,255,0])` Will be true if either the blue component is 255, or the green component is 254, or the red component is yellow (OpenCV uses BGR order for RGB by default).

If you want to detect pure yellow, (0,255,255) in BGR, then you need to ensure all three color components match, not any one component matches. The condition should be `np.all(game_img[y][x] == [0,255,255])`