Why is the image result flipped by 90 degrees?
I am trying to turn all of the white pixels in this image red, but when I run the program the shape is fine but the red pixels are rotated 90 degrees:

This is the current code that I am using to do this:
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2 as cv

def get_white_pixels(image_as_array):
    threshold = 40
    indices = np.where(image_as_array >= threshold)
    width=image.shape[1]
    height=image.shape[0]
    cartesian_y=height-indices[0]-1
    np_data_points=np.column_stack((indices[1],cartesian_y)) 
    return cartesian_y, np_data_points, width,height

image = cv.imread("framenumber0.jpg")
ind, pixels, width, height = get_white_pixels(image)

#Goes through every pixel and changes its values
for i in range(0, len(pixels)):
    loc_x = int(pixels[i][0])
    loc_y = int(pixels[i][1])
    image[loc_x,loc_y] = (0,0,255)

cv.imshow('Modified Image', image)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

I do need the location of the white points as I will use them later for the second part of the project. I suspect the problem has something to do with the np.column_stack(). I have been reading the info page of the function but I still do not understand why this happens.
If you want to replicate here is also the image that I am using:


If you are using for loops over Numpy arrays, you have probably gone wrong. Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019059/2836621

Have a think about this. You know white is rgb(255,255,255), same as #fff when you do hex colours in HTML/CSS. You want to make white into red, i.e. rgb(255,0,0), so you basically need to zero the green and blue channels:
import cv2 as cv

# Load image
im = cv.imread('ZXo3LfmS.jpg')

# Zero the blue channel, then the green channel
im[..., 0] = 0
im[..., 1] = 0

# Save result
cv.imwrite('result.png')


You can actually zero blue and green in one go, with:
im[..., [0,1]] = 0


Note that the ellipsis (...) means "all the other dimensions I didn't bother enumerating". If I felt like enumerating them for some reason, I could use:
im[:, :, 0] = 0     # zero the blue channel
im[:, :, 1] = 0     # zero the green channel

