# generate image of certain resolution containing black and white noise

Tags: image-processing

How how would i generate an image of certain resolution containing black and white noise. I want to generate a number of images with each images noise being different. Prefer if done in console of either linux or windows but coding is ok if really have to. 
Cheers

Comment: This can be done in pretty much any image processing tool or library out there...

Comment: First select a resoultion, then loop the height and width, generate a random number, if it is above some given threshold, assign that pixel white color, else black. Simple.

Comment: may be this QA might be interesting for you [avr code not working i want to generate random numbers help please](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29296619/2521214)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows:

```
convert -size 512x512 xc:gray +noise random -colorspace gray noise.jpg
```

[image]

Replace `convert` with `magick` if using v7+ of **ImageMagick**.

If you mean pure black and white without shades of grey, and maybe would like a different size and a `PNG` format, use:

```
convert -size 600x400 xc:gray +noise random -colorspace gray -threshold 50% noise.png
```

[image]

If you want a different distribution of noise (gaussian, poisson, binomial) or to attenuate the noise, have a look at [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29011461/2836621).