How to convert a BMP image to RGB565 with ESP32 (Arduino)
I am currently working on a project involving an ESP32. The ESP32 retrieves a BMP image from a PHP page that converts a JPG to BMP. The ESP32 then needs to convert the BMP image into RGB565 data to be displayed using LVGL. The issue is not with the display or LVGL, as standard images are displayed correctly. However, when the converted image is displayed, it is recognizable, but the colored pixels appear to be randomly placed. The converted BMP image looks perfectly fine when viewing it on Windows.
Here are the codes that give me the mentioned problem.
PHP code to fetch and convert the image:
<?php
// Function to make a request to the Mouser API and fetch the image
function fetchAndConvertImage() {
    // API key for accessing the Mouser API
    $apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY';
    
    // URL for making a request to the Mouser API
    $url = 'https://api.mouser.com/api/v1/search/keyword?apiKey=' . $apiKey;
    
    // Data to be sent in the request
    $requestData = array(
        'SearchByKeywordRequest' => array(
            'keyword' => 'Thermistor',
            'records' => 0,
            'startingRecord' => 0,
            'searchOptions' => 'string',
            'searchWithYourSignUpLanguage' => 'en'
        )
    );
    
    // Encode the data in JSON format
    $jsonData = json_encode($requestData);
    
    // Set up the options for the POST request
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
            'content' => $jsonData
        )
    );
    
    // Create a context for the request
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    
    // Make the request to the Mouser API
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    
    // Decode the JSON response
    $responseData = json_decode($response, true);
    
    // Extract the image path from the response
    $imagePath = $responseData['SearchResults']['Parts'][0]['ImagePath'];
    
    // Read the image data from the specified URL
    $imageData = file_get_contents("$imagePath");
    
    // Generate a unique file name
    $fileName = uniqid('image_', true) . '.bmp';
    $filePath = __DIR__ . '/' . $fileName;
    
    // Get image dimensions
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);
    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);
    
    // Calculate row size including padding
    $rowSize = floor(($width * 3 + 3) / 4) * 4; // Each pixel is 3 bytes (RGB), and we need to ensure each row is a multiple of 4 bytes
    
    // BMP header
    $bmpHeader = pack('c', 0x42) . pack('c', 0x4D); // Signature BM
    $bmpHeader .= pack('V', 14 + 40 + ($rowSize * $height)); // File size
    $bmpHeader .= pack('v', 0) . pack('v', 0); // Reserved
    $bmpHeader .= pack('V', 14 + 40); // Data offset
    $bmpHeader .= pack('V', 40); // Header size
    $bmpHeader .= pack('V', $width); // Image width
    $bmpHeader .= pack('V', $height); // Image height
    $bmpHeader .= pack('v', 1); // Number of planes
    $bmpHeader .= pack('v', 24); // Bits per pixel
    $bmpHeader .= pack('V', 0); // Compression (0 = no compression)
    $bmpHeader .= pack('V', 0); // Image size (can be 0 when no compression)
    $bmpHeader .= pack('V', 0); // Horizontal resolution (pixels per meter)
    $bmpHeader .= pack('V', 0); // Vertical resolution (pixels per meter)
    $bmpHeader .= pack('V', 0); // Number of colors in the palette
    $bmpHeader .= pack('V', 0); // Number of important colors
    
    // Convert image data to BMP format
    $bmpData = '';
    for ($y = $height - 1; $y >= 0; --$y) {
        for ($x = 0; $x < $width; ++$x) {
            $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
            $color = imagecolorsforindex($image, $rgb);
            $bmpData .= pack('C', $color['blue']); // Blue
            $bmpData .= pack('C', $color['green']); // Green
            $bmpData .= pack('C', $color['red']); // Red
        }
        // Add padding to ensure row size is a multiple of 4 bytes
        $paddingBytes = $rowSize - ($width * 3);
        $bmpData .= str_repeat(pack('C', 0), $paddingBytes);
    }
    
    // Save BMP file
    file_put_contents($filePath, $bmpHeader . $bmpData);
    
    // Free memory
    imagedestroy($image);
    
    // Return file name
    return $fileName;
}

// Call the function to fetch and convert the image
$imagePath = fetchAndConvertImage();
echo "https://theyoungmaker.ddns.net/opencomponent/$imagePath";
?>


ESP32 code to retrieve and convert the BMP image:
bool getImageFromURL(String url) {
  http.begin(url);
  int httpCode = http.GET();

  if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
    WiFiClient* stream = http.getStreamPtr();
    size_t totalLen = http.getSize();
    size_t len = totalLen;

    // Allocate buffer for the image data
    uint8_t* bmp_data = (uint8_t*)malloc(len);
    if (!bmp_data) {
      Serial.println("Failed to allocate memory for image data");
      http.end();
      return false;
    }

    // Read data into buffer
    size_t index = 0;
    while (http.connected() && (len > 0 || len == -1)) {
      size_t size = stream->available();
      if (size) {
        int c = stream->readBytes((char*)(bmp_data + index), size);
        index += c;
        if (len > 0) {
          len -= c;
        }
      }
      delay(1);
    }

    // Parse BMP header
    if (bmp_data[0] != 'B' || bmp_data[1] != 'M') {
      Serial.println("Not a valid BMP file");
      free(bmp_data);
      http.end();
      return false;
    }

    uint32_t dataOffset = *((uint32_t*)(bmp_data + 10));
    uint32_t width = *((uint32_t*)(bmp_data + 18));
    uint32_t height = *((uint32_t*)(bmp_data + 22));
    uint16_t bitsPerPixel = *((uint16_t*)(bmp_data + 28));
    uint32_t compression = *((uint32_t*)(bmp_data + 30));

    if (bitsPerPixel != 24 || compression != 0) {
      Serial.println("Unsupported BMP format");
      free(bmp_data);
      http.end();
      return false;
    }

    // Allocate buffer for the image data in 16-bit format (RGB565)
    size_t imgSize = width * height * 2;
    gui_img_nouveau_projet_png_data = (uint8_t*)malloc(imgSize);
    if (!gui_img_nouveau_projet_png_data) {
      Serial.println("Failed to allocate memory for image data");
      free(bmp_data);
      http.end();
      return false;
    }

    // Convert pixel data to 16-bit (RGB565) format
    uint8_t* src = bmp_data + dataOffset;
    uint16_t* dst = (uint16_t*)gui_img_nouveau_projet_png_data;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        uint8_t b = *src++;
        uint8_t g = *src++;
        uint8_t r = *src++;
        *dst++ = ((r & 0xF8) << 8) | ((g & 0xFC) << 3) | (b >> 3);
      }
      // Skip padding bytes if any
      src += (4 - (width * 3) % 4) % 4;
    }

    // Set image descriptor data
    gui_img_nouveau_projet_png.header.always_zero = 0;
    gui_img_nouveau_projet_png.header.w = width;
    gui_img_nouveau_projet_png.header.h = height;
    gui_img_nouveau_projet_png.data_size = imgSize;
    gui_img_nouveau_projet_png.header.cf = LV_IMG_CF_TRUE_COLOR;
    gui_img_nouveau_projet_png.data = gui_img_nouveau_projet_png_data;

    free(bmp_data);
    http.end();
    return true;
  } else {
    Serial.printf("HTTP GET failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
    http.end();
    return false;
  }
}

Does anyone know why this problem occurs? I'm unsure if the issue stems from the conversion from JPG to BMP on the server side or from the conversion from BMP to RGB565 on the ESP32. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
The original image:

The image displayed on the display:


Is the BMP that the server produces correct if you look at it on a different device? That would be the very first thing to check.

Yes, It is perfectly fine. However, I found that sometime, if the headers if the bmp are not correctly set, the computer can view it perfectly but the esp32 think it is not a valid bmp image.

If it's perfectly fine then you know it's the ESP32 code and not the server code which has the problem. If you know that it's generating incorrect bmp headers then you know that the server code isn't working properly...

The problem is that I dont know enough about BMP to even know what header are needed and the data in them (code is mostly written by ChatGPT..). But I am almost sure the problem comes from the esp32 code.

You need to work out whether the source of the problems is your PHP or your ESP32. Generate a bunch of random BMPs  as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29011461/2836621 and see if the ESP32 code renders them properly. Or just generate simple gradients and try sending them magick -size 320x200 gradient:red-blue image.bmp then you'll see if the colours and shapes are being interpreted correctly.

I used a test image like you suggested and the shape are all good. the only wrong thing are the color. The image I used is : https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/data/bmp/snail.bmp
But on the display, it is in purple tint. Does anyone think it could be because of swap (16 bit swap) that would be needed?

If you make a solid blue image using ImageMagick, you will see if it comes out blue. magick -size 320x240 xc:blue blue.bmp Likewise for green and red magick -size 320x240 xc:lime green.bmp and magick -size 320x240 xc:red red.bmp.

I was able to correctly display the image by swapping the bit of the image and then flip it vertically. Here is the corrected function :
bool getImageFromURL(String url) {
    HTTPClient http;
    http.begin(url);
    int httpCode = http.GET();

    if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
        WiFiClient* stream = http.getStreamPtr();
        size_t totalLen = http.getSize();
        size_t len = totalLen;

        // Allocate buffer for the image data
        uint8_t* bmp_data = (uint8_t*)malloc(len);
        if (!bmp_data) {
            Serial.println("Failed to allocate memory for image data");
            http.end();
            return false;
        }

        // Read data into buffer
        size_t index = 0;
        while (http.connected() && (len > 0 || len == -1)) {
            size_t size = stream->available();
            if (size) {
                int c = stream->readBytes((char*)(bmp_data + index), size);
                index += c;
                if (len > 0) {
                    len -= c;
                }
            }
            delay(1);
        }

        // Parse BMP header
        if (bmp_data[0] != 'B' || bmp_data[1] != 'M') {
            Serial.println("Not a valid BMP file");
            free(bmp_data);
            http.end();
            return false;
        }

        uint32_t dataOffset = *((uint32_t*)(bmp_data + 10));
        uint32_t width = *((uint32_t*)(bmp_data + 18));
        uint32_t height = *((uint32_t*)(bmp_data + 22));
        uint16_t bitsPerPixel = *((uint16_t*)(bmp_data + 28));
        uint32_t compression = *((uint32_t*)(bmp_data + 30));

        if (bitsPerPixel != 24 || compression != 0) {
            Serial.println("Unsupported BMP format");
            free(bmp_data);
            http.end();
            return false;
        }

        // Allocate buffer for the image data in 16-bit format (RGB565)
        size_t imgSize = width * height * 2;
        gui_img_nouveau_projet_png_data = (uint8_t*)malloc(imgSize);
        if (!gui_img_nouveau_projet_png_data) {
            Serial.println("Failed to allocate memory for image data");
            free(bmp_data);
            http.end();
            return false;
        }

        // Convert pixel data to 16-bit (RGB565) format with byte swapping
        uint8_t* src = bmp_data + dataOffset;
        uint16_t* dst = (uint16_t*)gui_img_nouveau_projet_png_data;

        // Calculate padding
        size_t rowSize = (width * 3 + 3) & ~3;  // Each row is aligned to a multiple of 4 bytes
        size_t padding = rowSize - width * 3;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            uint8_t* rowSrc = src + (height - 1 - y) * rowSize;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                uint8_t b = *rowSrc++;
                uint8_t g = *rowSrc++;
                uint8_t r = *rowSrc++;
                uint16_t pixel = ((r & 0xF8) << 8) | ((g & 0xFC) << 3) | (b >> 3);
                // Swap bytes
                pixel = (pixel >> 8) | (pixel << 8);
                *dst++ = pixel;
            }
            // Skip padding bytes
            rowSrc += padding;
        }

        // Set image descriptor data
        gui_img_nouveau_projet_png.header.always_zero = 0;
        gui_img_nouveau_projet_png.header.w = width;
        gui_img_nouveau_projet_png.header.h = height;
        gui_img_nouveau_projet_png.data_size = imgSize;
        gui_img_nouveau_projet_png.header.cf = LV_IMG_CF_TRUE_COLOR;
        gui_img_nouveau_projet_png.data = gui_img_nouveau_projet_png_data;

        free(bmp_data);
        http.end();
        return true;
    } else {
        Serial.printf("HTTP GET failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
        http.end();
        return false;
    }
}

